# What is the niyyat for nafl namaz?

Tags: salat, nafl

I always say the niyyat or intention in my language, because I don't know so would anyone help me to tell the niyyat in arabic with transliteration.

Comment: You can say niyyat in any language as Allah knows all languages.

Comment: The intention basically is in the heart it doesn't need to be pronounced! Some scholars would even consider pronouncing it a bid'ah.

Answer (score -1):

For four raka'ats Prayer(Fard) for example **'Isha'**
Pronunciation:

- > “Nawayatu An Ussallia Lillahi Ta'ala Arba'a Raka'atin Salata-l-**'Isha'** Faaradullahi Ta'ala Eqtadaaitu Bihazal Imami Mutawajjihan Ila jihati-l-Ka’bati sh-Sharifati, Allahuu Akbar”

  Translation:

  > (I Headed for ALLAH Intent to Pray **Isha’**s 4 Rakat ALLAH Taala’s Fard Prayer by Following This Imam Facing towards Kabah, ALLAH is Most Great)
  >   For Two raka'ats Prayer(Fard)

And for fajr/sobh fard
Pronunciation:

- > “Nawayatu An Ussallia Lillahi Ta'ala Arba'a Raka'atin Salata-l-**Fajri** Faaradullahi Ta'ala Eqtadaaitu Bihazal Imami Mutawajjihan Ila jihati-l-Ka’bati sh-Sharifati, Allahuu Akbar”

  Translation:

  > (I Headed for ALLAH Intent to Pray Fajr’s 2 Rakat ALLAH Taala’s Fard Prayer Facing towards Kabah, ALLAH is Most Great)

For three raka'ats Prayer(Fard) (**Maghrib**)

Pronunciation:

- > “Nawayatu An Ussallia Lillahi Ta'ala Arba'a Raka'atin Salata-l-**Maaghribi** Faaradullahi Ta'ala Eqtadaaitu Bihazal Imami Mutawajjihan Ila jihati-l-Ka’bati sh-Sharifati, Allahuu Akbar”

  Translation:

  > (I Headed for ALLAH Intent to Pray **Magrib**’s 3 Rakat ALLAH Taala’s Fard Prayer Facing towards Kabah, ALLAH is Most Great)

For three raka'ats Prayer(Witr Waajib)
Pronunciation:

- > “Nawayatu An Ussallia Lillahi Ta'ala Arba'a Raka'atin Salata-l-**Witri** Wajibullahi Taala Mutaowajjihan Ila Jihati-l-Ka’batish Sharifati, Allahuu Akbar”

  Translation:

  > (I Headed for ALLAH Intent to Pray **Witr**’s 3 Rakat ALLAH Taala’s Waajib Prayer Facing towards Kabah, ALLAH is Most Great)

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. OP asks for nafl prayers, except with witr which is considered as wajib by hanafis while it is a nafl or sunnah prayer for others you actually missed the topic of the question. Also "Allahu Akbar" is not part of the niyyah but one should say it right after making the intention.